# OS and subprocess return code 1 whenever execute shell commands with python

Tags: python, powershell, operating-system, subprocess

```
import os
os.system('ls')
```

> 1

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['cd'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

> CompletedProcess(args=['cd'], returncode=1, stdout=b'', stderr=b'')

Whenever I run these commands, my return code is 1. I tried uuninstalling and reinstalling powershell. I have python 3.9.1

Comment: what does this have to do with `powershell`? it looks like you are calling `cmd.exe` ...